# How to get Code Smells in Project History (from GitHub)

Tags: git, code-analysis, static-code-analysis, codacy

I need to retrieve the Code Smells introduced by each commit, coming from GitHub on existing projects.

I tried using [JDeodorant](https://github.com/tsantalis/jdeodorant), but it is not feasible to checkout the project for each commit to only do the analysis. I tried using PMD via the command line, however since there are many commits (an average 5000 per project), it was not possible to do this. The [Codacy](https://www.codacy.com/) tool gives me a similar result, however it does not display only CodeSmells and is also limited to 400 commits.

Any indication of where I can do this?

I can use any tool for this, as long as it returns some Code Smells defined by Matin Fowler.

Answer (score 0):

Both PMD and [Codacy](https://www.codacy.com) will run for a set of files, i.e. the current commit.
However, they will output all smells existing for a repository, not just for the code changed on that commit.

With Codacy you can know for each smell the commit and author who introduced it. It can also show you the smells being introduced and fixed in a given commit.